# change url without changing state in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i am using angularjs for developing SPA. i have state loading which there is image with a tag. this is required for a plugin i am using for creating album. but due to this my url is changing and this forces my state to change.

My question is how can i stop changing my state when url changes. or how to stop a tag to change url.

My app config :

```
var decorpot = angular.module('decorpot', ['ngRoute', 'satellizer']);

decorpot.config(['$routeProvider', '$provide', '$authProvider', function($routeProvider, $provide, $authProvider){

    $provide.decorator('ngViewDirective', function($delegate) {
        var directive = $delegate[0];
        directive.replace = true;

        return $delegate;
    });

    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'resources/partials/home.html',
        controller: 'DecorpotCtrl'
    }).when('/projects',{
        templateUrl : 'resources/partials/projects.html',
        controller : 'ProjectsController'
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });

}]);
```

image html :

Comment: problem sounds like it is due to plugin, not code shown. Not enough information provided for anyone to help with that

Comment: plugin requires anchor tag. So only thing i can do is either to stop change of url by anchor tag or change of state when url changes.

Comment: again, problem has to do with plugin, not the code shown.